# MYSQL Subtracting two tables with SUM

Tags: mysql

Table1

| projectname | referenceid | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Project1 | ref1 | 50 |
| Project1 | ref1 | 40 |
| Project1 | ref2 | 30 |
| Project2 | ref1 | 30 |

Table2

| projectname | referenceid | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Project1 | ref1 | 80 |
| Project2 | ref1 | 10 |
| Project2 | ref1 | 5 |

What I'd like to do is `SUM(quantity) GROUP BY projectname, referenceid` for each table. Then `table1.quantity - table2.quantity`. End result in this instance should be:

| projectname | referenceid | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Project1 | ref1 | (50+40)-80 =10 |
| Project1 | ref2 | 30-0 = 30 |
| Project2 | ref1 | 30-(10+5) =15 |

As you can see, there is no ref2 in Project1 in table2. So this makes it hard for me write the correct query.

I also would like to learn to write complex queries like this. Is there any documentation or course that i should study? How do i get there?

Comment: Incidentally, why do you have two similarly structured tables? This is sometimes symptomatic of poor schema design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate on the `UNION` of the 2 tables:

```
SELECT projectname, referenceid, SUM(quantity) quantity
FROM (
  SELECT projectname, referenceid, quantity
  FROM Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT projectname, referenceid, -quantity
  FROM Table2
) t
GROUP BY projectname, referenceid
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=240a536fd08ae3a1359d87036ccca1ff).
Results:

| projectname | referenceid | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Project1 | ref1 | 10 |
| Project1 | ref2 | 30 |
| Project2 | ref1 | 15 |

Comment: This solution is exactly what i am looking for. Thank you very much man!

Answer (score 0):

You could create two veiws to contain the projectname, ref and the sum of each table

```
Create view T1(prjName, ref,sum) as
select projectname, referenceid, SUM(quantity) 
from Table1
GROUP BY projectname, referenceid

Create view T2(prjName, ref,sum) as
select projectname, referenceid, SUM(quantity) 
from Table2
GROUP BY projectname, referenceid
```

Then you can subtract the sums based on same projectname and refereceid

```
select T1.projName, T1.ref, (T1.sum - T2.sum)
from T1, T2
where T1.projName = T2.projName
   and T1.ref = T2.ref
```

Note : this will be a slow process for large datasets

Comment: Note that queries against views in MySQL cannot access underlying indexes

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't quite understand what you are saying. I am new to sql. Can you please explain me with a few more words?

Comment: This solution, if it works, will be slow on larger datasets. It won't scale well.

Comment: Well thank you. I didn't think about that.